# how to insert the filename before inserting the file into another file in vim

Tags: unix, vim, vim-plugin

Is there a way we can insert the filename before we insert the file content into another file

i know how to insert a file into another -- :r

But how to insert the  filename which we are inserting before

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have the filename in a register (e.g. the system clipboard), you can insert that with `<C-r>+`. This also works with Vim variables: `<C-r>=g:filename<CR>`.

But usually, you'll just type the `:r filename`; then, the only shortcut to avoid typing it again is the filename completion (`:help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F`): In insert mode, type the beginning of the file name, then try to complete: `filen<C-x><C-f>`.

You *can* avoid the typing if you do it in reverse order: As the `:read` command sets the *alternate file*, you can insert that through the special register `#`:

```
:read filename
'[OI just added <C-r>#
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a small function to insert filename before reading the content:

```
fun! ReadwithFn(fname)
    let fn = expand(a:fname)
    if !filereadable(fn)
        echohl Error 
        echom fn." cannot be read!"
        echohl NONE
    else
        execute "put ='".fn."'"
        execute 'read '.fn
    endif   
endf
```

add define your own command:

```
command! -nargs=1 R call ReadwithFn(<q-args>)
```

if you source above codes, you could type

```
:R fileToRead
```

the function will first insert the path of the file, then comes the content. If the file not readable (doesn't exist for example) there is an error msg.

It is just basic script, you can tweak a bit.